# Errors with pandas merge function

Tags: python, pandas, merge, lookup, large-files

Currently trying to merge a file of ~6000 names with a file of ~90 million names and IDs. What I want to do is lookup the IDs for each of the 6000 names, resulting in a final output data frame of the 6000 names and their IDs.

To do so I am using this script:

**df2.merge(df1,left_on='name',right_on='NAME',how='left')**

df1 is the dataframe of 90 million rows; df2 is the dataframe of 6000 names. I'm using a left join because I want each of the 6000 names to remain even if an ID cannot be found for them. The difference in capitalization is consistent with the way the original files have their headers.

The script ran for over five hours and then "completed." However, the resulting df2 doesn't show any IDs and doesn't appear to have changed at all.

Wondering two things:

1. Is my code correct for this task?
2. Is there a faster method I could use to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `df2 = df2.merge(...)` ?

Comment: I would also suggest testing the merge logic on a small subset of `df1`, then figure out how to do the full merge once you know for sure it's doing what you expect. Something like `df1_subset = df1.iloc[:1e4].copy()`, then `res = df2.merge(df1_subset, left_on='name', right_on='NAME', how='left')`.

Comment: I'm an idiot...Michael your solution worked correctly. Thanks all!